# Program with "noexcept" constructor accepted by gcc, rejected by clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, noexcept

The code:

```
struct T { T() {} };

struct S
{
    T t;

    S() noexcept = default;
};

int main()
{
//    S s;
}
```

g++ 4.9.2 accepts this with no errors or warnings, however clang 3.6 and 3.7 report for line 7:

```
error: exception specification of explicitly defaulted default constructor does not match the calculated one
```

However, if the line `S s;` is not commented out, g++ 4.9.2 now reports:

```
noex.cc: In function 'int main()':
noex.cc:12:7: error: use of deleted function 'S::S()'
     S s;
       ^
noex.cc:7:5: note: 'S::S() noexcept' is implicitly deleted because its  exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ''
     S() noexcept = default;
     ^
```

Which compiler is right for the original code?

---

**Background:**

g++ even allows the following to be added to `main`:

```
std::cout << std::is_constructible<S>::value << '\n';
```

which outputs `0`. I encountered this problem when using clang to compile some complicated code that made heavy use of templates, SFINAE and noexcept. In that code `S` and `T` are template classes; so the behaviour depends on which types `S` was instantiated with. Clang rejects it with this error for some types, whereas g++ permits it and the SFINAE works based on `is_constructible` and similar traits.

Comment: Because in S constructor you'll get call to T constructor which could throw any exception.Clang is right, I believe

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux that's true about the exceptions but the issue seems to be whether the code should be rejected immediately, or whether the effect of `= default` should be to *define as deleted* which g++ seems to be doing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depends on the version of the standard you are consulting.

N3337 [dcl.fct.def.default]/p2:

> An explicitly-defaulted function [...] may have an explicit
>   *exception-specification* only if it is compatible (15.4) with the *exception-specification* on the implicit declaration.

which renders your original code ill-formed.

This was changed by [CWG issue 1778](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1778) to read (N4296 [dcl.fct.def.default]/p3):

> If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with an
>   *exception-specification* that is not compatible (15.4) with the exception specification on the implicit declaration, then
>
> - if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;
> - otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

which means that the constructor is now merely defined as deleted. (The above wording incorporated changes made by [N4285](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4285.html), a post-C++14 paper making some cleanup changes intended to be purely editorial. The N3936 version is substantively the same.)

Presumably GCC implements CWG1778's resolution, while Clang doesn't.

Comment: Which version appeared in published C++14 ?  (clang 3.7 still rejects the code with -std=c++14)

Comment: @MattMcNabb The issue has "C++14" status, so the second version should be in C++14. Note that this is a DR, so it probably will be implemented even in C++11 mode.

Comment: @MattMcNabb 4296 is pretty much what was voted as C++14 modulo typos and such

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Nah, 4296 has some C++1z stuff. I probably should quote 3936 or 4140.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you, didn't know it. I thought 4296 is it because official standard was marked by December 15 (?) 2014

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Completing the ballot on the draft and then working through all the bureaucratic paperwork takes time :) The C++14 draft was voted out of the committee in February 2014.

Comment: It seems that CWG1778 was reverted again for c++20: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html