# Why is default noexcept move constructor being accepted?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, default-constructor, noexcept

Assume the following c++17 code:

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace dtl
{
   struct One
   {
      explicit One(int);
      ~One() = default;
      One(const One &) = delete;
      auto operator=(const One &) -> One & = delete;
      auto operator=(One &&) -> One & = delete;
      One(One &&); // Throwable, not default;
      int m_int;
   };
   struct Two 
   {
      explicit Two(int);
      ~Two() = default;
      Two(const Two &) = delete;
      auto operator=(const Two &) -> Two & = delete;
      auto operator=(Two &&) noexcept -> Two & = delete;
      Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;
      One m_one;
   };
   One::One(One &&) { throw 1; }

   static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Two>);
}
```

[Code at compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/n3fa9b)

Here we clearly see that the move constructor of the class `One` ain't marked as noexcept. Class `Two` has a defaulted move constructor that is explicitly requested to be noexcept.

If we check this code, this compiles with GCC trunk, Clang trunk, MSVC 19.28 and fails with MSVC19.24.

I checked the following sources which seem to tell me that the move constructor of `Two` needs to be deleted:

- [Program with "noexcept" constructor accepted by gcc, rejected by clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483120/program-with-noexcept-constructor-accepted-by-gcc-rejected-by-clang/29483269#29483269)
- ['noexcept = default' compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032077/noexcept-default-compilation-error)
- [Bug 35204 - std::chrono exception specification of explicitly defaulted default constructor does not match the calculated one](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35204)

[CWG issue 1778](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1778) to read (N4296 [dcl.fct.def.default]/p3):

> If a function that is explicitly defaulted is declared with an exception-specification that is not compatible (15.4) with the exception specification on the implicit declaration, then
>
> if the function is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration, it is defined as deleted;
> otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

Based on that information, I can only conclude that all 3 compilers are wrong in considering `Two` as no_throw_move_constructible and the move constructor should be implicitly deleted. As it's strange for all 3 to ignore the standard on this, I do wonder: Is this really a compiler bug or am I missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you are looking at outdated information. DR1778 has been superceded by [P1286R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html). If you look at the [implementation status](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), you will see that gcc 10 and clang 9 implement this new resolution.

Indeed, if you go back to older gcc versions in godbolt, it tells you:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:35:25: error: use of deleted function 'dtl::Two::Two(dtl::Two&&)'
   35 |     auto b = std::move(a);
      |                         ^
<source>:23:7: note: 'dtl::Two::Two(dtl::Two&&) noexcept' is implicitly deleted because its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification ''
   23 |       Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;
      |       ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

You can find the gcc discussion [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2019-09/msg00311.html). According to [this list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:Cubbi), P1286R2 was accepted as a DR, meaning that it was retroactively applied to previous standards. As such, newer compilers will behave in the way that you noticed, independent of the chosen C++ standard.

At runtime, however, this will fail as expected:

```cpp
dtl::One::One(int) {};
dtl::Two::Two(int) : m_one(0) {};

int main() {
   auto a = dtl::Two{1};
   try {
      auto b = std::move(a);
   } catch (...) {
      // Even though an exception is thrown, it will not be caught here because
      // we broke our `noexcept` promise.
      std::cout << "caught" << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

```
[:~/tmp] $ /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/11.0.0/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 mv.cpp  && ./a.out
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type int
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, so am I correct to say that `Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;` behaves as if we would have written `Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;` and will call `std::terminate` if an exception is thrown?

Comment: You wrote `Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;` twice, but yes, `terminate` will be called. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oeps, copy-paste error, I meant `noexcept {}` iso `noexcept = default; `. Sounds good, thanks